# CakePHP BlowfishPasswordHasher Invalid Cipher because of salt?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, bcrypt, blowfish

I'm trying to perform the simple authentication tutorial on the cakephp site but I'm getting the "Invalid Salt" message when I try to log a user in.

- The passwords are being encrypted and inserted into the database
- The database column is long enough to hold the whole string

In CORE\Utility\Security.php _crypt it checks that my salt begins with "$2y$", "$2x$", or "$2a$" but they **do not**. I'm encrypting them with

```
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
```

Can anyone tell me why my salts are invalid? I don't understand why they don't start with the expected strings?

Comment: My salts do not start with the correct strings. I reworded my question. I don't understand why they don't start correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!!!!

My Php version was 5.2 and in order for blowfish to work properly it should be 5.3 or higher. I changed it to 5.5 and now it's working fine. YAY!!

Answer (score 0):

Either your salt is invalid (which you've already determined it's not), or **it's less than 29 characters**.

```
//Cake/Utility/Security.php
if ($salt === true || $invalidCipher || strlen($salt) < 29) {
    trigger_error(__d(
        'cake_dev',
        'Invalid salt: %s for %s Please visit http://www.php.net/crypt and read the appropriate section for building %s salts.',
        array($salt, 'blowfish', 'blowfish')
    ), E_USER_WARNING);
    return '';
}
```